# Session check list

Tags: php, security

Hi I have a security related question I allow users to login and register my question is when  a user logs in my script just sets the session no cookies so is it safe to only rely on sessions not on cookies? or I use both the cookies and sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP sessions use cookies to track the ID of the session. Thus, it is safe, because you actually are using cookies.

It's worth noting that you should try to prevent [session-hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) - you can do this by validating the IP of the user among other things in your `$_SESSION` object.

**Edit**

I suggest you read [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3472581/PHP-Tutorial-Sessions.htm). Quote:

> The session_start( ) function generates a random Session Id and stores
>   it in a cookie on the user's computer (this is the only session
>   information that is actually stored on the client side.)  The default
>   name for the cookie is PHPSESSID, although this can be changed in the
>   PHP configuration files on the server (most hosting companies will
>   leave it alone, however.)  To reference the session Id in you PHP
>   code, you would therefore reference the variable $PHPSESSID (it's a
>   cookie name; remember that from Cookies?)

Note: **stores it in a cookie**

Comment: I'm using session_regenerate_id() and I'm checking user agent when logging in also when I check I only see the php session id that is what my script is setting however when showing details I use $_SESSION['userid']; is it right to do so?

Comment: something everyone/you/me need to know http://shiflett.org/articles/session-hijacking and http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database :P trust me nothing is more informative/useful than those article

Comment: @NullPointer I'm not saving user_agent in cookie but in session

Comment: Yeah it's right to do so...... however `$_SESSION['userid'];` won't return the session id if that's what you're trying to do...

Comment: no, it is working I disabled the cookies and even they are disabled I'm still logged in that means `$_SESSION['userid'];` is returning and because I save the session data in db. Also to prevent from xss or csrf attack I'm using anti csrf tokens on forms only and to prevent from session fixation I use session_regenerate_id().